# What are good pre-internet books or courses for the creation of a logotype?

Tags: logo, resource-recommendations, book

I am a software engineer attempting the impossible: to codify logotype creation.

I want to learn all the rules and principles for logotype design and don't want to rely on blogspam.  I'm looking for timeless, pre-internet information.

What are the definitive books and courses that career logo designers have read and taken?

Comment: Hi Vidbot! Welcome to GD. This is a great question, let's see what people recommend.

Comment: I understand it is the moderator's job to clarify things, but my original question was "What are the **definitive** books or courses for the creation of a logotype?"  I am not looking for merely "good" books or courses.  I am looking for the books and courses that career graphic designers have read or taken that helped shaped them into the professionals they became.  Please pardon my clarification.  I do not mean to appear like a message board troll.

Comment: I just wanted to limit the scope a little. "The definitive" book would sound more like a suggestion question. You can edit the question back (just click on Edit).

Comment: It's not pre-internet and it's not 'definitive rules', but the most *useful* book on logo design principles I've seen is [Really Good Logos Explained](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JEBE_Ie6eHMC). It's great *because* it doesn't try to invent definitive rules for something which is fundamentally case-by-case - instead, it embraces this case-by-case nature by structuring itself around real straight-to-the-point no-nonsense critiques of real logos for real clients, with short profiles of the client giving crucial context.

Answer (score 3):

I would have to recommend Doyald Young's books. If you don't know who he is, you can check out a short documentary of him and his work: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8_tOrJHIr8

http://doyaldyoung.com/books.html

Comment: Great video.  This is exactly the kind of experience I was looking for, although I hoped to get more "rules" out of it.  A couple of good nuggets in there though:  #1 The logotype must be legible.  #2 The logotype must be unique.  His books also lead me to additional resources.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Lettering for Advertisements by Mortimer Leech